# iOS5: Determine if core data method is running in an asynch dispatch queue?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

How can I tell if a method is running asynchronously or not?

I have several core data related methods which are sometimes called asynchronously via an asynch dispatch queue (GCD) and other times are called synchronously.

```
// sometimes this happens
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
  [[DataServices sharedInstance] doSomeCoreDataStuff:^(BOOL result, NSString *message) 
  {
      // do some post-stuff here        
  }];
});

// other times this happens
[[DataServices sharedInstance] doSomeCoreDataStuff:^(BOOL result, NSString *message) 
{
    // do some post-stuff here        
}];
```

In addition to this, I am using a singleton `NSManagedObjectContext` throughout my app. Since context is not thread-safe, in the case when the core data methods are running asynchronously I need to create a new context within those methods, otherwise I want to use the singleton instance context.

The only approach that comes to mind is something like `[[NSThread mainThread] isMainThread]`, but GCD may or may not do work on the main thread, so this will not work.

Comment: If you're calling `dispatch_async`, why is there even any question about this?

Comment: "I have several core data related methods which **may or may not be** running in an an asynch dispatch queue..." The meaning is easy to miss, though. Updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: "... **like this:**", followed by code that uses `dispatch_async`. Are there other cases where you're not using `dispatch_async`?

Comment: Yes. I meant the methods will sometimes be called async, sometimes not. It was not at all clear. Updating question.

Comment: why don't you just add an argument to your `doSomeCoreDataStuff:` method that tells the Singleton whether it needs a new MOC?

Comment: @ChrisH I'm not a fan of adding a dependency like that. The view controller should not know that much about how the data layer needs to operate.

Comment: The view controller only needs to know whether it's making an async call or not. The data manager has two methods - `doSomeCoreDataStuff:` and `doSomeAsyncCoreDataStuff:` the implementation of which is totally up to the manager. Allows the data manager to encapsulate all that `performBlock:` stuff too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to deal with this is to configure your managed object context to use one the thread confinement concurrency types-- `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` or `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`-- and then use its `performBlock:` method when you want to use it. That is,

```
[[DataServices sharedInstance] performBlock:^{
    // do Core Data stuff here
}];
```

You can do that on any thread or queue, and it's asynchronous. There's also `performBlockAndWait:` if you need to get the results immediately.

You'd use that call *everywhere*. The only exception is if you use `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` and you **know** that you're running on the main queue, you could make calls on the context directly instead of via `performBlock:`

Comment: I completely forgot iOS5 introduced parent/child relationships for `NSManagedObject`! Thanks Tom. For those interested in this topic, Cocoanetics has a good article on the subject: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

Comment: Thanks for that article. Hadn't really paid any attention to those relationships either. The parent writer context idea is great.